# How to use StringBuilder(int length) in Java

Tags: java

According to java doc, I got this idea:

> StringBuilder(int length) in java ,creates an empty string Builder
>   with the specified capacity as length.

I tried the code below:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(9);
```

But I can append length more than 9.

```
sb.append("123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789");
```

What is the meaning of assign this length?

Comment: It doesn't mean that you cannot put more than 9 characters in the `StringBuilder`; it just means that it reserves space for 9 characters when you create the `StringBuilder`. When you put in more characters, it will grow automatically. The capacity is not fixed to what you pass the constructor, it's just the **initial** capacity.

Comment: Why don't you read the javadoc? It says: *Every string builder has a capacity. As long as the length of the character sequence contained in the string builder does not exceed the capacity, it is not necessary to allocate a new internal buffer. If the internal buffer overflows, it is automatically made larger.*. The javadoc is your friend. Read it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Comment: Tried reading the existing javadoc?

Answer (score 2):

When you use StringBuilder repeatedly, it re-allocates its buffer each time that it needs to accommodate a longer string. If you know that your target string is going to be of a certain length, you can save on re-allocation by telling StringBuilder the length of your string.

This is going to be the length of the initial allocation; appending under this limit is not going to cause re-allocations. However, StringBuilder would not have a hard limit: going beyond the initial size is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The value that you passed in the constructor is the StringBuilder's initial capacity. Its not equal to the length of the string being built by it.